# update records of a column in mysql by adding a value to middle of the string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a column called 'url' in 'table' whose records are in the pattern 'http://example.com/value/372954412/'.

I want to update these to 'https://www.example.com/value/372954412/'. The size of the table is huge. How do I go about this?

Comment: Just use `REPLACE` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to replace a string with another is `REPLACE`:

```
update my_table
set url = replace(url, 'http://', 'https://www.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the REPLACE in build function

***select replace('http://example.com/value/372954412/','http://','https://www.')***

Answer (score 0):

Update the column using <kbd>[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)</kbd> function.

**Query**

```
update my_table
set url = replace(url, 'http://', 'https://www.');
```

### <kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2f2a5/1)</kbd>